# Estoy tratando de resolver un sistema de EDOs con el método de Euler, pero no obtengo resultados

Tags: python, funciones, variables, script

Estoy tratando de resolver un sistema de EDOs con el método de Euler, pero no obtengo resultados. Cuando ejecuto el programa no obtengo una solución, y lo he hecho para diferentes tiempos. No encuentro mi error.

SOLUCIÓN NUMERICA (EULER):

```
inicio = time.time()

nk = 200 # tamaño del sistema.
npt = 100 # número de pasos de tiempo.
dt = (20)/npt # paso de tiempo.

pk = np.zeros(nk) # Distribución inicial igual a cero.

#Condiciones iniciales:

pk[10] = 1 

pkt = pk.copy()

# CICLO DE TIEMPO:

for n in range(npt):

    pk[1] = pkt[1] + dt*(2*pkt[2] - pkt[1])

    pk[2:nk-1] = pkt[2:nk-1] + dt*(2*pkt[3:nk] - 2*pkt[2:nk-1])

    pkt = pk.copy()   

kk = np.linspace(0,nk-1,nk)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))  
plt.axes( xlabel='S', ylabel='P(S)')
plt.plot(kk, pk, 'c.')

fin = time.time()
print(fin-inicio)
```

Comment: Hola, te da algun tipo de mensaje o error?

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunos cambios en el códigos. Dale una mirada con detalle. Además agregue para que haga la grafica . Si no la queres visible solo elimina: plt.show()

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

inicio = time.time()

nk = 200 # tamaño del sistema.
npt = 100 # número de pasos de tiempo.
dt = (20)/npt # paso de tiempo.

pk = np.zeros(nk) # Distribución inicial igual a cero.

#Condiciones iniciales:

pk[10] = 1
pkt = pk.copy()

# CICLO DE TIEMPO:

for n in range(npt):
    pk[1] = pkt[1] + dt*(2*pkt[2] - pkt[1])
    pk[2:nk-1] = pkt[2:nk-1] + dt*(2*pkt[3:nk] - 2*pkt[2:nk-1])
    pkt = pk.copy()

kk = np.linspace(0,nk-1,nk)
plt.figure(1)
plt.axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
plt.plot(kk,pk)

fin = time.time()
print(fin-inicio)
plt.show()
```

Resultado devuelto en Python:

```
 0.04687786102294922
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los parámetros para plt eran incorrectos:

```
# parametros erroneos
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))  
plt.axes( xlabel='S', ylabel='P(S)')
plt.plot(kk, pk, 'c.')
```

Comment: Podrías explicar al menos brevemente, el alcance de tus cambios, cómo se deben usar y por qué resuelven la pregunta? Decir "este es el código" no es muy útil, sobre todo para quienes lean esta pregunta en el futuro.

Comment: @Alfabravo Hice una actualización con las líneas de código corregidas. En realidad el código no imprimía nada. Creo que se debería cambiar el titulo.